# angularjs ng-init value to display in default then change after greater then 0

Tags: angularjs

I have a really long expression that shows"infinity" in default mode because its doing the math as soon as the app loads.

So as a solution, I thought if i set the ng-init value to myText="0", I could get it to show the zero then once a specific box value is greater than the 0, do the math calculations.

here is my my angular expression in the html. Its just adding a bunch of input boxes and dividing it by dynamicInputListResult.

Just want to set the value as 0 initally, then when something is actually in the dynamicInputListResult or if its greater then 0, to do the calculations. Any help would be great!

```
 <span style="font-size:28px" ng-hide="myVar" ng-init="myText='0'"> Week(s): {{myText}}  {{(factors.Delivery -- factors.systemProcess -- factors.contentMaterials -- factors.SME -- dynamicSliderbox[0] -- dynamicSliderbox[1] -- dynamicSliderbox[2] -- multipliesResult) / dynamicInputListResult }}</span>
```

Comment: I see multiple problems with this.  First, this isn't really a recommended use for `ng-init`;  `ng-init` is a directive with a priority, which means it could be processed at a later time than you expect.  Beyond that, doing a large calculation like this in the UI instead of in the controller is problematic.  Also, this doesn't look like a calculation anyway;  what is up with the `--` throughout?

Comment: the -- is the only way I can get it to add them together, wierd but it works.

Comment: Im basiclaly just trying to get the word "infinity" to not show up initially.

Comment: You are saying that -- is representing addition?  That makes even less sense, and further illustrates my point that this should be done in the controller

Comment: I saw this used in a a tutorial. It adds correctly though

Comment: well it does *work*, because mathematically, `--` is equal to `+`.  that still doesn't make it *appropriate*.  that aside, what you are doing right now is setting `myText` to the string `'0'` then outputting it, a couple of spaces, and your calculation right behind it.  `myText` and the calculation have no relationship to each other.  If you did the calculation in the controller, you could manage how the output is presented.

Comment: to use `ng-init` for this task, you would also need to use `ng-show` or `ng-if`, but you are already using `ng-hide` to monitor some other property.  I can't stress enough, this *is not* something that you should be doing in the HTML.

Comment: you likely can't use `+` in your calculations because some (or all) of your values are strings and not numbers, which is indicating that you may have issues with your `ng-model` values other places in your code.  At some point you should consider revisiting your application logic rather than rely upon workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be great practice, but it solved my issue and this is how i learn. A solution to this is using css. First I displayed with display:none but did not work so I assigned the span a different ng-model and checked to see if the value in another box is >0. If so, change the color. It was time consuming but required only ng-model and ng-class modifications.

```
 <span style="font-size:28px;"> Week(s):<span style="font-size:28px; color:white" ng-hide="myVar" >  <span ng-model="xyz" ng-class="{'test2':dynamicInputListResult > 0}">{{(factors.Delivery -- factors.systemProcess -- factors.contentMaterials -- factors.SME -- dynamicSliderbox[0] -- dynamicSliderbox[1] -- dynamicSliderbox[2] -- multipliesResult) / dynamicInputListResult }}</span></span>
```